# How to generate several Home button clicks from a bluetooth device?

Tags: java, android

I want to make an application that get a button from any Bluetooth device (game-pad, etc) and generate several home button clicks so I want to know how generate the home button clicks.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To simulate a home button tap from your application,
use the following intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```